# Multiple entry in Access with one button

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, multiple-tables

I'm working on a database, that would basically work as an inventory of documents I'm keeping. For the sake of simplicity, let's name the database pdf_inventory. Now, in this database I have two tables: all and published.

"Published" contains all the pdfs that are the current version, while "all" contains every single pdf that ever touched my computer.

The two tables have the same keys: Version, ID, Title, Date_Of_Modification, Modified_By.

What I want to do, is put the two tables in a Form, where we can switch between them with a navigation button (done), and when I'm at the published tab, I want a button "Add entry", that pops up a window, which lets you input data for all the keys, and then obviously adds an entry to the published Table.

Now comes the trick: the entry shouldn't simply be added to the "published" table, BUT to the "all" table too (plus it would be great, if somehow this could also remove the previous version from the "published" table; without obviously removing it from the "all").

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Seems to me this could be simpler with one table (instead of two) which includes a field to record whether the document has been "published".

Comment: @HansUp Thank you, but sadly that isn't an option :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using either Macros or VBA. Simply write two append queries, one whose destination is the "all" table and the other destined for the "Published" table. Have those queries reference your form controls to get the input data. Write a delete query for your "published" table that references the primary key of the record being viewed on your form, then execute the append and delete queries using a macro or VBA snippet embedded in the `OnClick()` event of your command button. (This may cause trouble depending on your table relationships, especially if you have referential integrity turned on) You will likely want to requery each of your table objects after the append executes so you can immediately see the new record from your form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I understood and will try to execute it and get back to you. One follow-up question only: why/how would an append querry in the end help? Simple `refresh all` wouldn`t update the tables in the forms?

Comment: So, I managed to do everything you told me, and it works. It copies well into the `all` table. 
I do get a problem though: with the delete querry, I get an error, saying that `Could not delete from specified tables.`
How I did it, is I ran a querry to find the Same document ID with the previous primary key (an auto number field), and delete that one. When I view the result of the querry, it is the correct entry, but executing it yields the above mentioned error. Do you know why this might happen ?